# SSH connection to remote server fails - RSA key is not allowed

Tags: ssh, rsa, windows-server-2016

I am trying to connect to my remote server via SSH and I cant figure out, what I am doing wrong. I read lot of threads, forums or other questions, but not a single helped.

Things that I done:

I installed OpenSSH from https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-install-an-openssh-server-client-on-a-windows-2016-server/

generate key using this command **ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096**

In config file changed this settings:

```
ChrootDirectory E:\OpenSSH\sftpfile
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
PermitTTY no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
SyslogFacility LOCAL0
LogLevel DEBUG3
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  C:\Users\user.name\.ssh\authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

Authorized keys file and .shh folder have this permissions:

```
FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : Write, Read, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : HAVELHOLASEK\user.name
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```

And error massage is :

```
debug1: trying public key file C:\\Users\\user.name\\.ssh\\authorized_keys
debug2: C:\\Users\\user.name\\.ssh\\authorized_keys:1: check options: 'ÿþs'
debug2: C:\\Users\\user.name\\.ssh\\authorized_keys:1: advance: ''
debug2: check_authkeys_file: C:\\Users\\user.name\\.ssh\\authorized_keys: processed 1/1 lines
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: RSA key is not allowed
Failed publickey for user.name from xx.xx.xx.xx port xxxx ssh2: RSA SHA256:LFNovUmpzpX5fcuvwBwFKYofuOxGTAQo+RuCNcsRr2c
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg rsa-sha2-512 [preauth]
```

I cant figure out, why it is not allowed. I know OPEnSSH blocks SHA-1 by default, but I an not using it, as far as I know.

Meaby it is a basic question, but I couldnt find answer in any similar older questions as I spent hours trying to make it work.

**UPDATE**

changed encoding of authorized_keys worked, and know my key is accepted.

Comment: `debug2: C:\\Users\\user.name\\.ssh\\authorized_keys:1: check options: 'ÿþs'` tells you there is something wrong with your `authorized_keys` file. Make sure it makes sense when utf-8 decoded.

Comment: No.. I stand corrected, it actually worked, thanks!